# Designing a mutable complex class and its construction in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

I am designing a complex Configuration class as part of an API design. The Configuration class roughly looks like this.. (I ignored generics/access modifiers etc)

```
class Configuration {
    One obj1;
    Two obj2;
}

class One {
      List<Double> values;
}

class Two {
      double value;
      Map<String, Double> data;
}
```

This is what I want to accomplish:

- I want users to be able to create this Configuration class the first time easily and submit to server.
- Then they can change any part of this class and send the updated configuration to the server.

What design patterns to use and avoid?

Is it better to make this class Immutable and use builder pattern?
Or just provide all kinds of modification methods On Configuration class so they can modify the same Configuration class (at all levels) in-place without having to create a new Configuration class for every update. I think Builder pattern is good for Immutable classes only.

Questions:

- Is there any way to exploit Builder pattern for this type of scenarios?
- Or is it better to provide mutator methods on Configuration class like I mentioned above?
- Or are there any other better patterns available?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use prototype pattern:
in your code you can add map that hold all types of configurations
the map will have a key called "currentConfiguration" and the value will be the configuration that should be loaded. the map can also contains other configurations that can be stored in the map and can replace the current configuration if needed.
once you fetch configuration from the map you simply clone the configuration object and the user can do what ever he pleased with that. after the changes he can save the configuration in the map with speicifc name. so the user can get configuration object that is quite close that what he needs and configure it accordingly.
the code should look like this:`public class CloudRepository {

```
private Map<String, Configuration> rep;

public CloudRepository(Configuration current){
    rep = new HashMap<String, Configuration>();
    rep.put("current", current);
}

public Configuration getConfiguration(String string){
    return (Configuration) rep.get(string).clone();
}

public void addConfiguration(String name, Configuration conf){
    rep.put(name, conf);
}

public void replaceCurrentConfiguration(Configuration conf){
    rep.put("current", conf);
}
```

}

you can also write more code to handle history for your configurations.
you can also consider making this class singleton